# SQL combine records with same wildcard value

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a MySQL Wordpress database and I'm dealing with the postmeta table which isn't nicely structure. It has four columns: "meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value". This is the query I am working with:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT * 
        FROM wp_10_postmeta as pm
        JOIN wp_10_posts AS p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE (meta_key LIKE 'personnel_%_last_name' OR
                meta_key LIKE 'personnel_%_first_name' OR
                meta_key LIKE 'personnel_%_title' OR
                meta_key LIKE 'personnel_%_alias' OR
                meta_key LIKE 'webpages_%_title' OR
                meta_key LIKE 'webpages_%_alias' OR
                meta_key LIKE 'departments_%_name' OR
                meta_key LIKE 'departments_%_alias')
            AND post_status = 'publish' AND meta_value LIKE '%john%' AND meta_value LIKE '%smith%'
```

**Issue**: This query works great if I search for "john" or "Smith" but if I do "John Smith" it return empty. Is there a way to combine "personnel_%_last_name" and "personnel_%_first_name" and then compare?

Comment: What values are in the meta_value col?

Comment: It's a directory of employees and departments, so pretty much just strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to look across multiple fields for the match.  Try using a `group by` for this purpose:

```
    SELECT p.*
    FROM wp_10_postmeta as pm JOIN
         wp_10_posts AS p
         ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    WHERE (meta_key LIKE 'personnel_%_last_name' OR
            meta_key LIKE 'personnel_%_first_name' OR
            meta_key LIKE 'personnel_%_title' OR
            meta_key LIKE 'personnel_%_alias' OR
            meta_key LIKE 'webpages_%_title' OR
            meta_key LIKE 'webpages_%_alias' OR
            meta_key LIKE 'departments_%_name' OR
            meta_key LIKE 'departments_%_alias')
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY p.id
    HAVING SUM(meta_value LIKE '%john%') > 0 AND SUM(meta_value LIKE '%smith%') > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using the group by method, however I'm getting strange results, for example a search for %michael% AND %humphries%, returns some one in my directory named "Nancy". Here is my SQL my php code is running: http://pastebin.com/d2DzxL0w

Comment: I noticed that what is returned are always 0 like: personnel_0_first_name . For example here is a search: http://pastebin.com/fpu8K7E3

Comment: If you want the matches to be to a particular meta key, then you need to include that key in the `having` conditions as well:  `sum(meta_value like '%join%' and meta_key like 'personnel_%_first_name')`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean. I ran this SQL http://pastebin.com/hzFb1hqf and got this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zif0jurh74wy1lz/Screenshot%202014-09-18%2010.13.05.png?dl=0